# c++ both 'if' and 'else' statement appear to be called

Tags: c++, if-statement

I have the following if-else statement in my code, which I am using to display a value to the user on a GUI:

```
if (data.steering.fpTTGValid)
    {
      pFlightPlanTTGReadout->setValid();
      pFlightPlanTTGReadout->update((int)data.steering.flightPlanTTG);
    }
else
    {
      pFlightPlanTTGReadout->setInvalid();
    }
```

When running the program in debug, and attaching to process in Visual Studio, if I hover the cursor over the `data.steering.fpTTGValid` variable in the 'if' statement, I can see that its value is true. My understanding is that this should mean that the code inside the subsequent `{}` executes, but the `else` statement should not execute.

However, as I continue to step through my code, I see that the `data.steering.flightPlanTTG` variable value stays at 0- suggesting that the `update()` function into which it is being passed has not executed. This variable also stays at 0 where it is displayed in the GUI, which would suggest that the `else` clause of the `if` statement has been called.

Since the `fpTTGValid` variable was true initially, my guess is that both the `if` and the `else` clause are being called- so that I never actually see a value displayed on the GUI, because the variable that would display it is set to 0 by the `setInvalid()' function.

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong here? Why isn't the value of the `data.steering.flightPlanTTG` variable being updated by the `update()` function even though the value of `data.steering.fpTTGValid` is true?

The `update()` function is defined with:

```
void ElapsedTimeReadout::update(const int total_seconds_)
{
SESL_FUNCTION_BEGIN(update)

int seconds, minutes, hours;
int update_delta = total_seconds_;

seconds = update_delta % 60;
update_delta = (update_delta - seconds) / 60;

minutes = update_delta % 60;
update_delta = (update_delta - minutes) / 60;

hours = update_delta % 24;

channel.Hours   = hours;
channel.Minutes = minutes;
channel.Seconds = seconds;

SESL_FUNCTION_END()
}
```

Comment: are you sure it is not just evaluating the if and then hitting the else? i doubt both are being called since that would represent a major bug. and it seems from your statements that you think it should be going into the if but is actually going into the else which would mainly be due to a logic error.

Comment: simple test: put debug statements into both paths, something that outputs DIFFERENT text. I will eat a shiny penny if you get BOTH statements...

Comment: For this `pFlightPlanTTGReadout->update((int)data.steering.flightPlanTTG);` you expect the *parameter* value to change? Not with that cast.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried removing the cast, but I'm having exactly the same issue... any other suggestions?

Comment: @jgr208 it does appear to be going into both the `if` and then the `else`, since when I debug the code and attach it to process, I can see that the boolean value in the `if` statement is true, but the execution of the `else` statement is what I see happening in my program...

Comment: @someone2088 ok have a print statement in if that says in if and another in else that says in else and tell us your result.

Comment: `ElapsedTimeReadout::update` doesn't change the value of `data.steering.flightPlanTTG`. Why are you expecting it to?

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure it isn't being updated? The odds are pretty small that both clauses of the if/else are being executed, that would be a pretty serious compiler bug and I'm pretty sure *somebody* would have noticed it by now. It's far more likely that your update function is either incorrect or that data.steering.flightPlanTTG ends up being zero when cast to an int.

Comment: I agree about the bug statement, from his explanation I am thinking more of a logic error.

Comment: Yeah, I wouldn't have thought that both the if and else statements are being called, but that is how the code appears to be behaving as I run through it in debug- I was just describig what I'm seeing... I'll add the code for the `update()` function now.

Comment: Code for `update()` function added.

Comment: Your update function doesn't. I.e., it may be updating the channel values, but it has no effect on data.steering.flightPlanTTG. In fact, I see no indication that update() is intended to change its input parameter at all. Bames53's answer pretty much covers it.

Answer (score 2):

> Why isn't the value of the `data.steering.flightPlanTTG` variable being updated by the `update()` function even though the value of `data.steering.fpTTGValid` is true?

If the `update()` function is really supposed to update its parameter then your code is incorrect. When you cast `data.steering.flightPlanTTG` you are creating a temporary variable, and any updates to that temporary variable will not be reflected in the original `data.steering.flightPlanTTG`.

In fact, if `update()` is supposed to update its parameter, then it's presumably taking the parameter by reference:

```
void update(int &param)
```

C++ does not allow you to pass a temporary to a function like this. You should get an error. The reason for this is to prevent exactly the bug you've written.

Unfortunately Visual Studio happens to have an extension that allows passing temporaries to functions like this. It does however have a warning which you can enable. You should turn the compiler's warning level up to 3 or 4 and fix all of the resulting warnings.

The most immediate change you can make to fix the error is:

```
int updated_flightplan;
pFlightPlanTTGReadout->update(updated_flightplan);
data.steering.flightPlanTTG = updated_flightplan;
```

---

Now that you've posted the code for `update()`, it appears that the problem is that `update()` doesn't work as you expect. It doesn't take the parameter by reference or do anything to update the parameter. Instead the function appears to produce output in the form of some side effects on `channel`, whatever that is.

The upshot here is that the if-else statement is working normally and the problem is in your understanding of how to use `update()`: The code

```
pFlightPlanTTGReadout->update(data.steering.flightPlanTTG);
```

is not supposed to modify `data.steering.flightPlanTTG`, and your expectation that it should is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

I believe typecasting the value to `(int)` will cause `flightPlanTTG` to become an RValue (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_(computer_science)#lrvalue) -- strictly speaking, a non-L-value -- which means it's not an expression whose value can be modified. You would also have to make sure that the `update` function is written in such a way that the parameter passed to it is passed by reference. Otherwise it will just be modifying a local copy of the value, not affecting the original value. Since you're not using the return value, the simplest and most readable fix would be to make the `update` function return a value instead of expecting it to modify its parameter directly. Then assign the result back to the `flightPlanTTG` value.

Comment: I tried removing the cast to `int`, but still have the same issue...

Comment: Remember I also said your update statement would have to be written in such a way that the parameter is passed to it by reference. See bames53's example. Looking at your update function, I wonder exactly at what point you would expect the parameter value to be updated. It's not updating the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

If `data.steering.fpTTGValid` is true/non-zero, then only the first block will execute. Have you checked the value of `data.steering.flightPlanTTG`? If that value is zero, then you're simply calling `update` with a parameter of `0`. Your conditional block looks fine. I would instead step into the `setValid` and `update` functions themselves. See whether `update` is being called with a non-zero parameter. Make sure that `update` is doing what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

> However, as I continue to step through my code, I see that the
>   data.steering.flightPlanTTG variable value stays at 0- suggesting that
>   the update() function into which it is being passed has not executed.
>   This variable also stays at 0 where it is displayed in the GUI, which
>   would suggest that the else clause of the if statement has been
>   called.

This is a completely wrong analyses because the code is clearly buggy.

If you wish to update data.steering.flightPlanTTG either it needs to passed using a pointer or using a reference. The update() function clearly does not use either mechanism.

Comment: I have asked him to prove that both are called by "print statement in if that says in if and another in else that says in else and tell us your result." yet he did not do this. Thus he makes it hard for us to even help.